# Number of entries and duplicated key leveldb for C

Tags: c, leveldb

What is a good strategy not overwriting the keys?

Suppose I perform **Put** operation twice with the same key, currently it doesn't raise an error but overwrite the old value .

I want to keep my old value .

One option is to do an extra read for every **Put** just to see if it is an overwrite or an insert. But then in this case for first element I need to check the size of my database as well.
my str is a incremental string , so next iteration of same code will have same key but different str.

```
leveldb_t *db;
leveldb_options_t *options;
leveldb_readoptions_t *roptions;
leveldb_writeoptions_t *woptions;
size_t read_len;
char *err = NULL;

/* OPEN */

options = leveldb_options_create();
db = leveldb_open(options, "testdb", &err);

if (err != NULL)
    return;
leveldb_free(err);
err = NULL;

/* WRITE */

woptions = leveldb_writeoptions_create();
leveldb_writeoptions_set_sync(woptions, 1);
leveldb_put(db, woptions, "Key", 3,  *str, 64 , &err);

if (err != NULL)        
    return(1);

leveldb_free(err);
err = NULL;
```

Comment: Can you post some code to show how you are using leveldb

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options:

- Include other information in your key - perhaps a timestamp of when the key was generated, or something to make it truly a key - a unique value - in such a way as you can find other similar keys.
- Store the values associated with the key as a list, then when you do a Put, simply append to the end of this list.

Leveldb is incredibly powerful but very simple. You're simply storing byte arrays, so it's completely up to you how to solve the problem. Think what logically makes sense, then work out how to put this into code.

Comment: Tough my keys are unique id but still I need to put an extra check , that key is not there in the database.

Comment: Can you post some code? That will help with getting other people to contribute and can help me see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You could append a millisecond timestamp and then a 64 bit random number to the keys? Pretty much certain to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Prefix the key with its `type`. For example, if your key is "Monkey" then prepare its key as "Animal:Monkey". LevelDB assumes keys given to it are unique and just overwrites with the latest value, if key exists